# Persistent entity 'Product' should have primary key

Tags: spring-boot, entity

Hover the class Product and you get 'Persistent entity 'Product' should have primary key'. From the quick search I did, I didn't find anything that was related.

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Table;


@Table(name="product")
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your entity class should have an ID field defined based on which jpa decides what type of primary key it needs to generate.

Define a field in entity class like below from the javax.persistence package.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

Comment: appreciate it .